Selection of aggregates from the repository based on a complex condition
When it is necessary to select aggregates from a repository based on a condition that matches a computed field of the aggregate, some code "duplication" occurs.
For example:
class Element:
  status: Status
  updated_at: Time

  def is_ready(self) -> bool:
    return self.status == Ready and self.updated_at < now().sub(1 * time.Hour)

It is necessary to implement a method in the repository to find "ready" Elements:
class ElementRepository:
  def get_ready(self) -> List[Element]:

To do this, an SQL query must be implemented with duplicated conditions WHERE status = 'ready' AND updated_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour'). If the logic of get_ready changes, the SQL query will also need to be changed.
Is there a way to describe this logic in one place?

Assuming bounded-context reflects "ready" elements only, you can have a class named ReadyElement which should NOT have the is_ready property, while get_ready method of ElementRepository returns List[ReadyElement]. This way you have a single place with the ready-specification.
One problem remains, though. Specifications should not leak to repository objects (Infrastructure layer). They belong to Domain layer, meaning you should have a mechanism converting native specifications to SQL clauses i.e. some kind of ORM (Object Relational Mapper).
So even if you design your bounded-context to have both Element and ReadyElement classes (along with two repository methods returning List[Element] and List[ReadyElement] respectively), you are going to present a single Domain specification that will be used a) inside Element class, and b) inside repository method returning List[ReadyElement].
